# How can I configure mutt to display my replies within threads?

Tags: email, mutt

While mutt has `set sort = threads` to show threaded, "conversation" style messages, it doesn't display one's own replies in the threads. Instead, you have to change to the Sent folder to see your own messages. Is there any way to display one's own replies where they belong inside threads?

Comment: Just save the send email in your current folder and not in the send folder?

Comment: But what happens if I reply on an email from my phone?

Comment: You should write up `notmuch-mutt` up as an answer and accept it. It works fine here!

Comment: I have since stopped using mutt and now use mu4e (mu for emacs). I will go ahead and answer this question though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that [notmuch-mutt](https://upsilon.cc/~zack/blog/posts/2011/01/how_to_use_Notmuch_with_Mutt/) has some of the behavior I'm looking for. It defines a macro that looks at message-ids and can create a virtual folder to show an entire threaded conversation regardless of where each message lives. Out of the box it only works on search results. I'm not sure if the same behavior can be applied to regular mailboxes.

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution that works for me even though it is not pretty.

```
set record = "+INBOX"
```

I just set record to my inbox, in that way the messages get threaded. It might not be ideal when I am the first sending an e-mail, but normally I will get an answer, so no issue.

Answer (score 2):

The common way to see your own messages in the threaded display, which makes sense, is done by sending a BCC to you.

I use

```
my_hdr Bcc: my@my.email.tld
```

and it works great.

Comment: This looks like a plain ugly hack to me. Sending copies of all emails to myself just feels wrong. Especially if it is to accommodate for a poor viewing code in the email client. I often search my Gmail inbox and include things such as `to:me`. Using the approach you suggest messes this up.

Comment: I did my own little investigation on this feature asked by OP and @aioobe and there seems to be no easy way to do that, so it's a good idea for a patch. There are already a [number of patches](http://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/PatchList) written for mutt by various people. It would be a great feature to have, btw!

Comment: Yes. I've started looking into writing a patch. I see it as a last resort though. (Same story for a 'mute' feature.)

Answer (score 2):

You can make a patched mutt save your message to the current folder.
To cite the [FAQ](https://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/MuttFaq/Folder#HowtosavecopiesofoutgoingsenteMailstothecurrentfolder):

> How to save copies of outgoing/sent eMails to the current folder?
>
> You need the current_shortcut patch (see PatchList). With that patch,
>   "^" points to the current folder. You can use that folder in
>   folder-hooks etc.
>
> folder-hook . 'set record="^"'
>
> Note: Make sure you have at least current_shortcut.2. Version 1 is
>   broken.

It seems that the Ubuntu 16.04 package ships that patch.

Answer (score 2):

`notmuch` is the solution, but it's several solutions, not one.

- I couldn't abide
  `set record = "+INBOX"`
  or the `my_hdr` BCC solution.
- I couldn't get the `fcc-hook` solution described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/577126/show-my-response-mutt) working (may be mutt only, not neomutt).
- so I got `notmuch` up for the "virtual folder" approach, and it provided a good solution, but not a great one (for me), and it was pretty complicated to get working and stable.

Luckily, along the way I found a great, simple, fast alternative solution *also* provided by notmuch:
**`<entire-thread>`**.

With `entire-thread` you leave the default the default (no replies visible; no virtual folders), but if my cursor/marker is on a thread and I want to see my replies in it, `entire-thread` will reconstruct the thread to include my replies.  Because this ended up feeling cleaner and easier, I ended up undoing the full-on switch to `notmuch` virtual folders and reverting to traditional folders.

Invoke it in your `.neomuttrc` with:

```
bind index + entire-thread       # or instead of `+` bind to `,+` or anything
```

---

Downsides are that

- if I want to see a message sent by me that's not part of a thread I still have to `<change-folder>` to `Sent`
- when I'm done viewing the entire thread I have to `<change-folder>` back to `Inbox`
  But `<change-folder>` isn't slow for me now that I'm doing header-caching right, so these are minor.

Context:

- I'm on neomutt on macos, on a macports build (lots of messing with variants to get here)
- I only have ~30K emails