# Show my response mutt

Tags: email, mutt

How do I view my response to an email? I do have an email I have previously responded to (it is marked with 'r' now). I am asking for a setting to always show my responses in threads. I would be happy with a command how to go to my response. I am using NeoMutt 20180716 (Debian 10).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following to your `.muttrc`:

`set sort = 'threads'`

Comment: I do sort by threads. But I needed to save the sent mail to inbox instead of Sent.

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody is struggling with this too. I found what I think it is the best solution if you use neomutt:

`fcc-hook . '+Sent,^'`

This saves *any mail* (the `.` will match anything) first in the `Sent` folder and then in the current (`^`) folder.

*Note that if you have several accounts, you need to call the hook each time you switch account so the `Sent` folder is changed to the new account.*

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
set record="=INBOX"
```

worked for me. It still feels a bit dirty.

Comment: It can be a little more complicated than it seems. f.e.: when you want to save to different mailboxes for different accounts or when you're sending encrypted email (you can't decrypt it once they're encrypted). For this purpose there is fcc-hook and fcc_clear.
Also it depends on your setup. f.e. if you're using gmail. You don't need to use it at all. Gmail saves automaticaly sent messages into Sent.